# Should datasource-specific restrictions be enforced in DAOs?

Tags: java, mysql, constraints, dao

Are there any recommended practises with respect to enforcing datasource-specific  restrictions ?

For example have an assertion or throw an Exception when a `String` is saved that exceeds the [255 or 65535 limit given in MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html). Or should this be handled by the datasource ?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to
>   65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a
>   VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size
>   (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character
>   set used. See Section E.7.4, “Limits on Table Column Count and Row
>   Size”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your data access layer the only validations you should be doing are those defined for your particular database schema. You can view the data access layer as the object representation of your schema, it should, as much as is reasonably possible, mimic the structure, data types, and constraints of the schema, ***but nothing more***. So, given the following trivial schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `passwordHash` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

You would validate, in data access layer, that:

- The `userName` property is set prior to saving, and it is a character sequence less than or equal to 64 characters in length
- The `passwordHash` property is set prior to saving, and it is a character sequence less than or equal to 256 characters in length

But, very importantly, you should rigorously avoid any checks that are tied *only* to a particular database implementation. For one, you want your data access layer to be provider agnostic, and secondly, most of those vendor specific restrictions would have fired the very instant you try to create your table.